# How to fix "IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds"?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, parsing

I saw a few similar questions but the answers didn't help. I'm making a parser for the first time in my life and seem to have made a mistake. I have a data file which is divided into months and years, and in each month, there are the same columns with different values ​​inside. Each new month begins with 21 cells. I made a parser for one month. I need to repeat this for each next one in the table. I tried to make a method to do this. I put the entire parser into a cycle that will be repeated until the cells run out. However, I have encountered an error while doing this.

Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import date, datetime
import datetime as DT
import time
import calendar
from pandas import DataFrame

# Empty dataframe where processed months are loaded
allmonths = pd.DataFrame()

dictionary = dict(December='12', January='01',February='02', March='03', April='04', May='05', June='06', July='07',
                  August='08', September='09', October='10', November='11')

df = pd.read_excel('C:/Users/shevc/Desktop/zbl/Shakh.xlsx')
# cut off excess caps from the data frame to count values
dfnew = df.iloc[3:, 4:]
# print(dfnew)

# the iterator takes the maximum index value in the table
perem = dfnew.index[-1]
prov = dfnew.index[-1]
#print(perem)

#variables to jump through cells
formonths = 0
forDF1 = 0
forDF2 = 0

for i in range(0, perem - 1):
    if perem == prov:
        formonths += 3
        forDF1 += 3
        forDF2 += 24
    else:
        formonths += 21
        forDF1 += 21
        forDF2 += 21

    # if the file ends, then exit the loop
    if perem < 0 | formonths > perem | forDF1 > perem | forDF2 > perem:
        break

    # for working with month
    months = df.iloc[formonths]['534']
    s = pd.Series(months)
    # print(months)

    # there is a split of the month and year and extraction of 1 and 2 elements
    months.split()
    # print(months)
    month = months.split()[0]
    year = months.split()[-1]
    # print(year)

    # dictionary and month comparison
    if month in dictionary.keys():
        result = dictionary[month]

    # converted to time format
    resulttimemonth = time.strptime(result, '%m')
    moonth = resulttimemonth.tm_mon
    resulttimeyear = time.strptime(year, '%Y')
    yeear = resulttimeyear.tm_year

    # find out the number of days in the month of the desired year
    days_in_month = calendar.monthrange(yeear, moonth)[1]
    #print(days_in_month)

    dti = str(days_in_month) + '.' + str(moonth) + '.' + str(yeear)


    new = df.T
    newest = new.iloc[6:, forDF1:forDF2]
    newest['date'] = dti
    newest.index = np.arange(len(newest))
    newest.columns = ['Qн ТМ', 'F вращ ТМ', 'ТМ Qж(тн)', 'Qж(тн)', 'Обв', 'Qж', 'Обв ХАЛ', 'Qж ТМ', 'F', 'Dшт',
                      'Qж ТМ (исх)', 'Рбуф ТМ', 'Qг (АГЗУ)', 'Ртр', 'Рбуф ТМ', 'ГФ', ' Обв ТМ ручн', 'Qн ТМ ручн',
                      'Pзаб(PпрTM)', 'Рзат ТМ', 'Примечание', 'Дата']
    #print(newest)

    # load each new month into a common dataframe one after another
    itog = allmonths.append(newest)

    perem = perem - 21


# make a new excel file from dataframe
itog.to_excel('C:/Users/shevc/Desktop/zbl/result.xlsx', startrow=0, index=False)
```

And this is the error I am getting.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/shevc/Desktop/збл/Prog1.py", line 45, in <module>
    months = df.iloc[formonths]['534']
  File "C:\Users\shevc\AppData\Local\Temp\Prog1.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 1424, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "C:\Users\shevc\AppData\Local\Temp\Prog1.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2157, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "C:\Users\shevc\AppData\Local\Temp\Prog1.py\venv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexing.py", line 2088, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

[image: How file with data looks like before parsing]
[image: And what I need to do. It<code>s only for december and with one mistake, that I</code>ll fix later (it`s 31 in all cells, but it will be 1 to 31 from beginning to end)]

Comment: it is a bit difficult to read some of the code because of the different language, but it appears that line 45 (months = df.iloc[formonths]['534'] is outside the actual excel data. Double check that the sheet you are reading corresponds to a value in your excel data. Also you might want to check out an easier library just for reading excel: pylightxl (link to docs: https://pylightxl.readthedocs.io)

Comment: Please provide a sample of the data you start with, and a sample of what you want the data to look like afterwards.

Comment: @Ukrainian-serge there is no tavle format here, i provided two images. First - the example of data I start with and second is a samble of what I want (it`s data for december only and I need something like that for november too)

Comment: @PydPiper I changed something for better understanding. And line 45 is correct, cause when I did this code for only one month - it is working correctly, but when added loops to do this code for all months in my table - it is crashed. I added the example of data before parsing and after (after is for one month only)